# How to delete xml nodes via a html form using php

Tags: php, html, xml, forms

Before I start, please be aware that I am fairly new to this.

I have a calendar which I eventually want users to be able to add, edit and delete events that are stored in an XML file, via a HTML form using PHP. So far I have managed to add, thanks to the tips found on this site, but I'm having difficulty with deleting.

I want the user to be able to enter the name of the event they want to be deleted, so that it can be found and removed from the xml file.

The problem is that when I input an event for deletion, the form will only delete events in the reverse order that they were entered, seemingly from the bottom of the xml file.

For example:
Through the HTML form I enter 4 events. Event 1, Event 2, Event 3, Event 4.

Suppose I want to delete Event 2. I use the delete form to delete Event 2, but Event 4 gets deleted. So I try again to delete Event 2, and this time Event 3 gets deleted.

Any help is much appreciated!

Many thanks.

This is what I have:

XML

```
        <calendar>

     <event>
     <name>Event 1</name>
     <startdate>21-3-2016</startdate>
     <enddate></enddate>
     <starttime>14.41</starttime>
     <endtime></endtime>
     </event>  

       </calendar>
```

HTML

```
<form action="remove.php" method="post" name="remove" id="calendarEdit">
<input class="calendarInput" type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Remove.php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml-> load('events.xml' ) ;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

foreach ($xpath->query("/calendar/event['name']") as $node);

{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild ($node);
}

$xml->formatoutput - true;
$xml->save('events.xml');

header('Location: calendar.html');
exit();
```

Comment: You never use `$name` in your delete code. you just loop (incorrectly) over all the events and try to remove them all.

Comment: What should I be using?

Comment: probably something more like `/monthly/event[text() = '$name']` for the xpath query...

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work. To confirm whether I understood right, I now have the line as `foreach ($xpath->query("/monthly/event[text() = '$name']") as $node)`

Comment: please post relevant code only. This will help to make your question clear and to the point. Learn debugging your code to focus on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
foreach ($xpath->query("/monthly/event['name']") as $node);
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild ($node);
}
```

You have a typo, the semicolon at the end of `foreach` declaration. By this way, your code means this:

```
foreach ($xpath->query("/monthly/event['name']") as $node)
{

}
$node->parentNode->removeChild ($node);
```

So, your `foreach()` do nothing else than updating `$node` content. Then, `->removeChild()` remove actual `$node` (last child).

Also your XPath query is wrong. To search for `<name>` nodes with 'Event 1' value, you have to create a pattern like this:

```
/calendar/monthly/event/name[text() = "Event 1"]
```

Note that `/` at start of pattern is used to search the **complete** tree starting from root element, so you have to use the complete descendant tree (I have started from `calendar` basing on your example).

If you want to perform a search ignoring element position, you have to use `//`. So if you want search for 'Event 1' starting from `<monthly>` item, your pattern is:

```
//monthly/event/name[text() = "Event 1"]
```

Last but not least: to remove “Event 1” you don't need a foreach loop, simply try this:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query( '//monthly/event[name[text() = "Event 1"]]' );
$nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild( $nodes->item(0) );
```

The `event[name[text() = "Event 1"]]` part of the pattern means: **retrieve `<event>` elements** having `<text>` child with “Event 1” value.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm not sure I understood. I removed the colon at the end of the    foreach declaration, but when I tested it, it wiped the xml file completely.

Comment: @HSwaff edited answer, with additional info about xpath syntax. My english is not good, so if it is not clear feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your help, fusion3k. There was confusion in the code in my original question - 'monthly' should have been 'calendar' - sorry, I have edited that, now. The tree should only have calendar and event.  I don't want to search for values, otherwise I have to put every value in the php. I want the user to enter the value in the html form and for the php to find it. So if I put Event 1 in the php, it will only ever look for Event 1 and not what the user wants to search for. Sorry if this is confusing, but I am new to coding. How can I make it search for what the user inputs?

Comment: Maybe you have to increase your php knowledge before writing code ;) You have to simply replace `Event 1` with your variable. So if - ie - your post variable is `$_POST['eventname']` replace `text() = "Event 1"` with `text() = "' . $_POST['eventname'] . '"` Otherwise, if your post var is the event number (i.e. 1), replace `text() = "Event 1"` with `text() = "Event ' . $_POST['id'] . '"`, etc... Pay attention to single/double quotes!

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should. I am probably attempting something that is way to complex for my level just yet. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.